# Django: Serving huge user-uploaded files in a Multi-server context

Tags: python, django, nginx, multiserver

I have to serve huge user-uploaded files for my Django app. So I opted for the following server structure:

`nginx (Main routing) <-> uWSGI <-> Django App [ONE MACHINE]
      | nginx [ANOTHER MACHINE hosting media and static]`

For permissions convenience, I would like all the files uploaded by users and others generated by the app to be created under my Django app, and then be moved to my storage server.

How can I proceed for the files to be uploaded to my storage server?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! "Transit through my Django app", i.e. serving static files through Django is a bad idea. It is better that the web server (Nginx, Apache2...) serves the files itself, as it is designed to do that efficiently. However, there is a possibility to check permissions in Django and serve a file with the web server if you use Apache2's mod_xsendfile. Maybe there is an equivalent for Nginx...

Comment: Could you please be more specific, what's the issue with your setup? As you describe, there's nothing special, just configure Django MEDIA the right way and add a custom model, which will return URL for your files leading to nginx backend. Any time user accesses the file browser will just go to that link and fetch it from nginx. Also, you can configure frontend nginx to upstream to backend when specific location, corresponding to stored files is requested.

Comment: Hi! I meant transiting through django on upload only. Edited the post to explicit. Also, question is on the uploading only. Serving does not need any permission check